# HTML5 Cache.Manifest for JSP pages?

Tags: jsp, html

im writing an Webapplication whith Jquerymobile and JSP and the Webapplication must have the posibility to work in Offline mode but i could not manage to make a jsp page run in offline mode over the cache.manifest i think its becouse a browser can not recognize the jsp content as html ?

Is it possible to use cache.manifest for jsp pages or not ?

This is my index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html manifest="/cache.manifest">
<body>
Hello World
<img src="j2ee1.gif" width="368" height="383" alt="tmp">
</body>
</html>
```

this is my cache.manifest

```
CACHE MANIFEST
NETWORK:

CACHE:
/index.html
/jee2.gif
```

regards

Kamis

Answer (score 2):

**Some ideas:**

1. You have to set the correct HTTP header for the manifest file in web.xml or your web server, web.xml sample below.
2. Given your code snippets the manifest is located in your servers *root* directory

**Register cache-manifest mime type in web.xml:**

```
<mime-mapping>
    <extension>manifest</extension>
    <mime-type>text/cache-manifest</mime-type>
</mime-mapping>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, for sure. You can cache everything using HTML 5 Cache Manifest.

Have you checked the spelling of the file in manifest ?

```
CACHE MANIFEST
http://site.com/page.jsp
```

Comment: @Kamis: Hopefully the target browser(s) support it :-)

Comment: thank you for the fast response i tried it now again and when i go with firefox in offline mode its working but when i shutdown the tomcat server its not working its strange :-(

Comment: @Kamis: which Firefox version?

Comment: its Firefox 4.0.1 i have also Chrome the latest and on that its also not working

Comment: might it be that when im in Offline modus that im not allowed to leave it ?

Comment: @Kamis: Let's stop chatting here. Have a look at my answer.

Answer (score 0):

In theory it might work with JSP, in reality it won't work for most JSP sites.
If you use *.jsp in your manifest it will save the generated html for offline use, not the Java-code.
You cannot save server-side code(be it Java, PHP, C#, CGI,...) for offline-use by the client.
Because (unless security is breached) server side code is not accesible on the client, and cannot be saved by the client.

So if there is little to no server-side Java in combination with your HTML, JavaScript,CSS it will work. But then there is no added value over a Pure HTML-page.
So in reality most WebSites with Server-side code(eg. JSP but also PHP, Rails, ASP.NET) will not work because the client HTML-code is generated on-the-fly by the server.